# Sql constraint method returns a false value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with a constraint method in sql.

**This is my table**

```
CREATE TABLE [relations].[CompoundKey_Contacts](
    [compoundId] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [personId] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [contactInfoId] [varchar](32) NOT NULL)
```

When you add a row to this table it should check that this combination of person and company does not already exist in the table. For this I use a constraint function

**Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE [relations].[CompoundKey_Contacts]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_CompoundKey_Contacts] CHECK  (([relations].[doesThisCompoundKeyExist]([personId],[companyId])='NO'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [relations].[CompoundKey_Contacts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_CompoundKey_Contacts]
GO
```

**Function**

```
CREATE function [relations].[doesThisCompoundKeyExist](
    @personId varchar(32),
    @companyId varchar(32)
)
returns varchar(3)
as
begin
    declare @exists varchar(32)

    if(@companyId is null and @personId is null)
      set @exists = 'YES'
    else if(@personId is null)
        if exists(select compoundId from relations.CompoundKey_Contacts where personId is null AND companyId = @companyId)
            set @exists = 'YES' 'This is where to code enters, but it should come to the else and return 'NO'
        else
            set @exists = 'NO'
    else if(@companyId is null)
        if exists(select compoundId from relations.CompoundKey_Contacts where personId = @personId AND companyId is null)
            set @exists = 'YES'
        else
            set @exists = 'NO'
    else if exists(
        select compoundId from relations.CompoundKey_Contacts where personId = @personId AND companyId = @companyId
        )
        set @exists = 'YES'
    else
        set @exists = 'NO'
    return @exists
end;
```

**My insert statement that fails**

```
insert into relations.CompoundKey_Contacts (companyId, contactInfoId, personId, compoundId) values ('COM-000015945', 'INF-000144406', null, 'CPK-000000067');
```

The problem is this. When I run an insert on the table with a unique insert it still fails. I have of course checked that it rely is unique with a select statement. And here comes the funny part. When I do debug it and check where it fails and break out that code part and run it free without being in a function it behaves as it should so the following code works if its not run in a function

```
if exists(select compoundId from relations.CompoundKey_Contacts where personId is null AND companyId = 'COM-000015945')
                print 'YES'
            else
                print 'NO' 'Returns NO as it should.
```

**This is the error msg I get**

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_CompoundKey_Contacts". The conflict occurred in database "domas", table "relations.CompoundKey_Contacts".
The statement has been terminated.
```

I run this on both a Sql Server 2012 and Sql Server 'DENALI' CTP3

Comment: What are actually trying to do in plain English please so I don't have to decypher the code

Comment: @gbn Im trying to avoid duplicates of (person,company) combination in my table. If there already is a key that has a certain (person,company) than a new insert should fail if I try to insert the same (person, company) but with a different key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a UDF in a check constraint won't work reliably as you can see

Use a unique constraint on a computed column if you require extra logic

```
ALTER TABLE CompoundKey_Contacts
    ADD CompoundKey AS ISNULL(personID, 'NOPERSONID') + ISNULL(companyId, 'NOCOMPANYID');
ALTER TABLE CompoundKey_Contacts WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_CompoundKey_Contacts_CompoundKey UNIQUE (CompoundKey);
```

Or a simple unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE CompoundKey_Contacts WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_CompoundKey_OtherUnique UNIQUE (personID, companyId);
```

Comment: Could you give an short answer on why UDF in check constraint doesn't work? I didn't get that part.

Comment: @Marthin: sorry, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756268/how-are-my-sql-server-constraints-being-bypassed/7756370#7756370

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique constraint or unique index on `personId,companyId`.

Don't try using a check constraint with a UDF for this as it is inefficient and difficult to get correct anyway.